# Getting java.sql.connection from Spring jdbc : getJdbcTemplate()

Tags: java, sql, spring, connection, jdbctemplate

In my application, we are trying to get java.sql.Connection from Spring,

`Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(this.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());`

I use this connection object to set the prepare statment and execute query to get result set.

I am aware of the concept that when we are using jdbcTemplate, the burden of opening the connection, closing the connection etc is taken by spring itself and we don't need to handle in the code explicitly.

But I am little bit confused in this case, Since we get the connection object explicitly from the jdbcTemplate, do we need to handle the connection closing also in the code explicitly ? We are using a connection pool.

Thanks in advance.

BD

Comment: why are you doing that if you have a jdbc template? You can use `execute` that gives you a `ConnectionCallback` if you really need to do some low-level stuff for some reason.

Comment: Actually this code is written by some other people long back, So I am not sure why we use that. But as part of re factoring, I was looking at this code

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of datasource you have configured (in your case its a datasource configured with connection pooling) so the same datasource is used by DatasourceUtils getConnection and hence the Connection object which you create will be pooled meaning if you call close on this connection object the connection wont be actually closed but instead will be returned to the connection pool

Comment: I am aware of this, but my doubt is whether we need to conn.close explicitly. After the transaction is complete, whether the connection will go back to pool since we gotthe connection object from jdbcTemplate

Comment: If you are using Spring transaction then as per the docs:-
"Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
If an existing transaction already has a connection synchronized (linked) to it, that instance is returned. Otherwise, the method call triggers the creation of a new connection, which is (optionally) synchronized to any existing transaction, and made available for subsequent reuse in that same transaction."


So no need to conn.close explicitly as the spring transaction commit/rollback would take care of releasing the connection to pool.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above depending on how the connection is obtained you will either close the connection or return it to the pool.

However as you are using JbbcTemplate there is no need for you to be dealing with connections at all as Spring will handle this for you.

You should define a row mapper to handle all the result set processing, and then just call the appropriate method on JdbcTemplate to excecute the statement for you. The Spring code will then

- get you an open connection
- execute the query process the result set
- map it to domain objects using the row mapper
- close the result set
- close the connection or return it to the pool

See [Spring documentation for JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) which explains in detail what you have to do and what Spring does for you.